# How can i Send form data as mail and still submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, form-submit, submit-button

I have a form in my site that my visitors will fill up and click submit and it will be submitted to the company I work for. How can I write a code that if submit button is clicked, will send the form details to a php file and still perform the original action(submit). I have written the php code already.

Comment: *"I have written the php code already."* - It'd be nice to know what that is.

Comment: there is no need to downgrade the question.  Just ask to see the code.

Comment: Why is `ActionScript` tagged in this question, are you involving (Adobe) Flash plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely going to need to know some front-end stuff for this. I recommend skipping straight to [`JQuery`](https://jquery.com/) using the below. Let me know if you have any questions, happy to help!

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post ("otherPage.php", $('#form').serialize()); //send data to php
  $('#form').submit(); //submit original form
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly well. Seems like I will look more into front end.  How do you  see this. Any advice? 
                                                                              for (i=0;i<document.forms.length;i++)
{
    var originalaction = document.forms[i].action;
    document.forms[i].action =
    "Otherpage.php?orig="+originalaction;
}

Comment: For some reason I didn't get this notification, but that syntax looks fine. Not sure if you still need help with this, but wouldn't that output be something like `"Otherpage.php?orig=Otherpage.php"` ?